# Tom was too kind to tell Sally the truth

Tags: meaning, infinitives, too

a. Tom was too kind to tell Sally the truth.

Can't that sentence mean two things?

1. Tom didn't tell Sally the truth, because he was too kind.
2. It was too kind of Tom to tell Sally the truth.

Many thanks

Comment: Similar idea but not the exact same thing.

Comment: Neither really. It means something like: "Tom didn't tell Sally the truth, because it would be hurtful to do so".  Essentially, he didn't want to hurt her feelings.

Answer (score 3):

It means that Tom’s kindness exceeded some threshold and as a result, his telling Sally the truth was impossible.

The collocation *too kind* as an expression of modesty or gratitude doesn’t work here. Maybe if you put it, “Tom was too kind **in telling** Sally the truth.” Or, for perhaps yet another meaning, “Tom’s telling Sally the truth was too kind.”

Comment: "too kind" meaning excessively nice would probably require a pause after it, with "to tell Sally the truth" offering an explanation of the way in which he was too kind. So you would probably put a comma after "too kind" if that was the sense.

Comment: You can be too kind to do something. Why not?